# Missing Params with HttpNtlmAuth

Tags: python, python-requests, parameter-passing

Hi so I am trying to setup a python scraper for work, and we are using NTLM Authentication (I know this because logging in is successful).

Using:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth


url = 'http://mywebsite.com/view.asp'
params = {'id': '123', 'key1':'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
auth = HttpNtlmAuth('domain\username', 'password')

r = requests.get(url, auth, params)

print(r.url)
```

Produced the output:

```
http://mywebsite.com/view.asp?id=123
```

I get logged in, but the rest of the GET values dont show.  If I change the order of the params, the first tuple will be shown:

```
params = {'key1':'value1', 'id':'123', 'key2':'value2'}
```

Outputs:

```
http://mywebsite.com/view.asp?key=value1
```

Without using HttpNtlmAuth, I don't get access to the page, but the output is

```
http://mywebsite.com/view.asp?id=123&key1=value1&key2=value2
```

If anyone could help, I'd really appreciate it, thanks!